# Flutter: Exoplayer: 404 from GCP bucket but the video plays fine in Chrome

Tags: flutter, video, http-status-code-404, exoplayer

There is an almost identical question on SO from 5yrs ago, but no answer:
[Android exoplayer video plays on emulator but not on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44227416/android-exoplayer-video-plays-on-emulator-but-not-on-device)

TL:DR

- Using Chewie, running the sample code from the repo.
- Sample URL plays fine
- My video is transcoded on GCP and in a bucket
- My video plays fine in Chrome
- My video plays fine in VLC on the test device
- My video encounters an error when played in Chewie:
- - "exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error"
- - "Caused by: ...exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$InvalidResponseCodeException: Response code: 404"
- Checked the sample URL again in the test device, it plays perfectly

Again, the code is the example from the Chewie repo. The code is unchanged, I am only changing the URL it's pointed at.

As Jar-Jar said, "Any help would be hot"

Answer (score 0):

The answer is I need more coffee. I'm leaving this here only to help others in the future.

Make sure when you paste your URL to the top of your list of sources, you put a comma at the end of the line. Otherwise it will consider the first two strings to be a single URL, which it will never be able to find.

Monday... the day when half of us say "I'm an idiot" at least 3x.